# Gijgo Grid doesn't bind data if I call action from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using gijgo grid to bind data. I did it two ways using gijgo grid.

1)First Binding data with html helpers to html table and doing CRUD with Gijgo,it binds data,do CRUD but does not reload grid on add,edit and delete.

```
  <table id="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="56">ID</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Brand</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Model</th>
                        <th width="64" data-tmpl="<span class='material-icons gj-cursor-pointer'>edit</span>" align="center" data-events="click: Edit"></th>
                        <th width="64" data-tmpl="<span class='material-icons gj-cursor-pointer'>delete</span>" align="center" data-events="click: Delete"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }


                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

in delete function,grid doesn't reload after deleting

```
           function Delete(e) {
           if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
               $.ajax({ url: '/Home/Delete', data: { id: e.data.id }, method: 'POST' })
                   .done(function () {
                       //grid.reload({ page: 1});
                       grid.reload();

                   })
                   .fail(function () {
                       alert('Failed to delete.');
                   });
           }
       }
```

2) Then I did a different implementation of gijgo grid binding data via ajax call of gijgo using this example

[Gijgo Grid example](http://gijgo.com/Grid/Demos/PagingAndSorting)

The Get function returns JSON

```
            public JsonResult Get(int? page, int? limit, string sortBy, string direction, string brand, string model)
        {
            List<CarsViewModel> records;
            int total;

                var query = _context.Cars.Select(p => new CarsViewModel
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Brand = p.Brand,
                    Model = p.Model

                });


                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model))
                {
                    query = query.Where(q => q.Model != null && q.Model.Contains(model));
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(brand))
                {
                    query = query.Where(q => q.Brand != null && q.Brand.Contains(brand));
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(direction))
                {
                    if (direction.Trim().ToLower() == "asc")
                    {
                        switch (sortBy.Trim().ToLower())
                        {
                            case "brand":
                                query = query.OrderBy(q => q.Brand);
                                break;
                            case "model":
                                query = query.OrderBy(q => q.Model);
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (sortBy.Trim().ToLower())
                        {
                            case "brand":
                                query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.Brand);
                                break;
                            case "model":
                                query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.Model);
                                break;

                    }
                    }
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    query = query.OrderBy(q => q.o);
                //}

                total = query.Count();
                if (page.HasValue && limit.HasValue)
                {
                    int start = (page.Value - 1) * limit.Value;
                    records = query.Skip(start).Take(limit.Value).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    records = query.ToList();
                }


            return this.Json(new { records, total }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }



 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

               grid = $('#grid').grid({
                   primaryKey: 'Id',

                  dataSource: '/Home/Get',
                   columns: [
                       { field: 'Id', width: 56 },
                       { field: 'Brand', sortable: true },
                       { field: 'Model', sortable: true },
                       { width: 64, tmpl: '<span class="material-icons gj-cursor-pointer">edit</span>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Edit } },
                       { width: 64, tmpl: '<span class="material-icons gj-cursor-pointer">delete</span>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Delete } }
                   ],
                   pager: { limit: 5 }
               });

               dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   resizable: false,
                   modal: true,
                   width: 360
               });
               $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
                   $('#Id').val('');
                   $('#Brand').val('');
                   $('#Model').val('');
                   dialog.open('Add Car');
               });
               $('#btnSave').on('click', Save);
               $('#btnCancel').on('click', function () {
                   dialog.close();
               });
               $('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
                   grid.reload({ page: 1, name: $('#txtBrand').val(), nationality: $('#txtModel').val() });
               });
               $('#btnClear').on('click', function () {
                   $('#txtBrand').val('');
                   $('#txtModel').val('');
                   grid.reload({ brand: '', model: '' });
               });});
```

which results in JSON returned in this format

{"records":[{"Id":7,"Brand":"toyota","Model":"matrix"},{"Id":8,"Brand":"Mazda","Model":"M3"}],"total":2} and gives error unable to bind data like 
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**

If I remove the record and total section and put raw json as datasource like this 
[{"Id":7,"Brand":"toyota","Model":"matrix"},{"Id":8,"Brand":"Mazda","Model":"M3"}]
then data is bound but again grid.reload() doesnt work. I am really frustrated why this issues are there. First the gijgo grid server side controller code returns JSON dataas record with total and then I am not able to bind it with the code that gijgo has provided in jquery. Then grid.reload() isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Could you review our ASP.NET examples where everything is setup correctly. You can find them at https://github.com/atatanasov/gijgo-asp-net-examples